# How to query the WorkFlowAlert MetaData object?

Tags: soql, email-alert

I need send a list of all the email alerts a user is registered to.

Is there an easy SOQL command that I can use?

I can query the 'CC Emails' using workbench:

> select Id, description, ccemails from WorkflowAlert

But I also want to access the 'Recipient lists'. How is this object registered on the WorkflowAlert object?

++++++++

I found that the data exists on the WorkFlowAlert metadata object.
How can I query that?

++++++++++++++++++++++

I found that I can query a single object's Metadata - is there a way to mass query that?

Old question Subject
Is there a way to get a list of all the email alerts a user is assigned to?

Comment: You could probably use ant to retrieve all alerts, and here will be mentioned user names

Comment: that's what did. feel free to answer this for credit